# How do I translate the following code for my asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF Publish Subscribe Service. The publisher would be a asp.net and the subscriber would be a winform app. How do I translate the following code for my asp.net to read and perform the way for it to connect to my service?

```
class Program : IPostingContractCallback
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InstanceContext site = new InstanceContext(new Program());
        PostingContractClient client = new PostingContractClient(site);

        client.PublishPost("testing");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shut down data source");
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources
        client.Close();
    }

    public void PostReceived(string postSampleData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})",postSampleData);
    }
```

Comment: Pubish/Subscribe in WCF is not well supported. What do you want to do exactely ?

Comment: The above code is meant for a C# application that when runs, acts as a publisher that publish to the service. what I wan to do is to translate that to asp.net code as my publisher is a asp.net webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to translate the service code using the following command

> svcutil.exe /language:vb /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8888/PostingContract

And adding the following codes to my asp.net

```
Dim site As InstanceContext = New InstanceContext(New json2())
Dim client As PostingContractClient = New PostingContractClient(site)

client.PublishPost(alertId:="")
client.Close()

Public Sub PostReceived(alertId As String) Implements IPostingContractCallback.PostReceived

    Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})", alertId)

End Sub
```

Comment: that creates a proxy to a WCF service, it doesn't 'translate' the service code. Perhaps semantics, but important I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want your asp.net page to act as a publisher.

I do not think that this will work. The problem is that the asp.net page only lives for a very short time. If you try and pause it like you pause your code, you will get a timeout and the page will stop working.

However, if what you want to do is have the publisher running on the server side you should host it in a windows service.